# How to install Sun's JDK on CentOS?

Tags: installation, java, centos, rpm, jdk

I having difficult time installing Sun's JDK on CentOS. The default installing with "yum" is "openJDK", but I need to install Sun's JDK.  Is there easy instruction out there I can use or any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle no longer supports JDKs earlier than 7, however, you can still download them from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html).  For the latest version, go [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp).

Choose your version and architecture.  You want the Linux version.  Get the .rpm.bin version.

Using the root account, or the sudo command, run the file you downloaded (chmod it if necessary). This will extract & install the Java packages.

You are done.   You can run `java -version` in your terminal to verify.  Also take a look at [CentOS wiki about SunJDK](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaOnCentOS#head-0830905309344b2b52bcd6fc5c699b651c666701)

You can see what got installed by running `rpm -qa | grep java`.

Comment: If you don't want JavaDB installed, try `unzip jdk-6u26-linux-i586-rpm.bin jdk-6u26-linux-i586.rpm`, then `rpm -ivh jdk-6u26-linux-i586.rpm`, this will install only JDK.

Comment: I am getting "Package jdk-6u26-linux-i586.rpm is not signed" -- any ideas?